# Copy, combine certain columns in CSVs and output to a new file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have csv files `a.txt` and `b.txt` (no header, tab separated), each one has 6 columns and roughly 200,000 rows, and always same row numbers in each file, what I have to do is:

- Copy all the first 4 cols from `a.txt` **>** output to a new file `c.txt`
- Get 5 col in `a.txt` **+** 5 col in `b.txt` **>** output to 5 col `c.txt`
- Get 6 col in `a.txt` **+** 6 col in `b.txt` **>** output to 6 col `c.txt`

Sample of `a.txt`

```
B sub   19  20  IG_BSU00010     4   1
B sub   22  23  IG_BSU00010     0   0
B sub   35  36  IG_BSU00010     0   0
B sub   55  56  IG_BSU00010     0   0
```

Sample of `b.txt`

```
B sub   19  20  IG_BSU00010     0   2
B sub   22  23  IG_BSU00010     0   0
B sub   35  36  IG_BSU00010     0   0
B sub   55  56  IG_BSU00010     1   0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A KISS solution,

1. open all the files we need,
2. loop forever, reading a line from `a`, testing for EOF and possibly breaking out
3. read also from `b`, split the lines, update the last two items in `la`, output the joined elements and write a newline character

.

```
a = open('a.csv')
b = open('b.csv')
c = open('c.csv','w')

while True:
   la = a.readline()
   if not la: break
   lb = b.readline()
   la = la.split('\t')
   lb = lb.split('\t')
   la[4] = str(int(la[4])+int(lb[4]))
   la[5] = str(int(la[5])+int(lb[5]))
   c.write('\t'.join(la)); c.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
target_file = open('a.txt','r')
data_from_a_file = target_file.readlines()
```

Then you can split each line by spaces

```
formatted_data = [line.split(' ') for line in data_from_a_file]
```

In `formatted_data` you will get list where each line of your file will be presented as separate list, like this `[['sub', '19', '20'], ['other', 'values']]`
.
 And then you can easily access it like `formatted_data[1][5]`  -  that will give you 6th value of second line